# Cannot save the date with different format with the SQL server date format

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

My server has MM/dd/yyyy format. I'm saving surveys from users and it includes the date when they submitted the survey. But some users got an error which is The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a date time data type resulted is an out-of range value. This is when I use datetime.now to save the date of survey.And when I check their computers they have different date format. So I tried changing it to the server date format and it works but these users don't want to change their date format so is there any possible solutions without changing the date format in their computer.

```
            .AddWithValue("@SurveyDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.NOw
            .AddWithValue("@EDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now
```

Comment: Argh! DO NOT convert anything to text that is not text.  If you are saving a date to a database then save a `Date`, not a `String`.  If you want the current date without the time in VB then use `Date.Today`.

Comment: Why are you converting to a string? date/time information is NUMERIC (in SQL Server is is actually 2 integers)  Just because we see dates "in a format" does NOT mean it is stored that way. Dates are Dates, not strings.

Comment: Sorry for that but when I directly pass the values of the DateTime.now into the parameter, it gives me the same error. This error only happens for those users who are using dd/MM/yyyy format in their computer but for other users, it runs smoothly,

Comment: It is IMPOSSIBLE to have an issue with date form if you work with binary date values at all times. Either there is no issue and you are imagining it (e.g. reading something incorrectly somewhere) or else you're the one creating the issue in the first place by converting a `Date` to a `String`.

Comment: That error can't possibly occur in the code you posted.  The error message mentions conversion from text to date, which is not happening here.  Do some proper investigation of the issue and find out where it's actually occurring, then post a new question specific to that problem with the information relevant to that problem.  Don't change this question so that everything posted so far becomes irrelevant.  If this question is no longer relevant then delete it.  If and answer provided has actually helped then accept it. Either way, post a new question for what is effectively a different problem.

Comment: Show your table and stored procedure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
 Dim dt As Date = DateTime.Today

.Add("@SurveyDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dt
.Add("@EDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dt
```

Note that I have corrected your use of `String` instead of `Date` as well as correcting your use of `AddWithValue` instead of `Add`.  If you are going to use `AddWithValue` then use it properly, i.e. specify the value:

```
.AddWithValue("@SurveyDate", dt)
.AddWithValue("@EDate", dt)
```

The idea with `AddWithValue` is that you provide the value and the data type is inferred from that.  The problem with that is that the wrong data type may be inferred.  For instance, SQL Server has `date`, `datetime` and `datetime2` among others for dates.  Which will be inferred in this case?  It's better not to assume or care and just call `Add` and specify the data type you want.

Comment: Sorry for that but when I directly pass the values of the DateTime.now into the parameter, it gives me the same error. This error only happens for those users who are using dd/MM/yyyy format in their computer but for other users, it runs smoothly

Comment: If you are being affected by the local date format then you are doing something wrong because format is ONLY an issue when displaying dates as text. A .NET `DateTime` value is EXACTLY the same no matter where in the world you are or what your local settings are. Your system date format only affects how dates are DISPLAYED, NOT how they are STORED. If you are having issues with date formats then it MUST be because you are converting to a `String` somewhere. Stop doing that and your issue goes away.

Comment: If you do as I have demonstrated here then there can be no issue. Please explain EXACTLY what you are doing, EXACTLY what happens and EXACTLY why you think this is not correct.  Please edit your question and add ALL these details and I mean ALL the details.  Don't be vague and don't leave out relevant stuff for the sake of brevity.  You're doing something wrong here so we need to know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it clearly. My server has MM/dd/yyyy format. Im saving surveys from users and it includes the date when they submitted the survey. But some users got an error which is The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a date time data type resulted is an out-of range value. This is when I use datetime.now to save the date of survey. So I thought this is because the user date format is different from the server date format. But as you said that this is nothing to do with this problem. What's the difference between datetime.now and datime.today? I will change my question.

Comment: The difference between `DateTime.Now` and `DateTime.Today` is exactly as it is explained in the documentation for each.

Comment: I found that this problem only appears for those user using windows 10 os. Why so?

Comment: Because of something that you are doing that you haven't shown us.

Comment: Im sorry for not showing you the full code. This program has been transferred to me so I am not aware of all the codes. The problem I found is that there's an error in the assignment of values from label passing the text to a date time data type.

Comment: It is wrong to be taking a date from a `Label` in the first place. A `Label` is for display of data, not storage of data. If a date is displayed in that `Label` then it must have come from somewhere in the first place. That original source is where you should be getting the `Date` value from. Depending on what that source is, you might need to declare a field of type `Date` and assign the value to that, then display that field value in the `Label` as well as using it elsewhere. I realise that you probably didn't write that code so no need to stipulate that.